# What was the exact content of the warning signal transmitted from the derelict in Alien?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

I've always assumed that the transmission did not give many details about the xenomorph's biology, other than it was a dangerous organism. In other words, the transmission could probably be summarized as "Warning. Extremely dangerous organism. Stay away." But I don't know this for certain. I would like to know the exact content of the transmission, if that data exists. Also, I seem to recall reading somewhere that Weyland-Yutani executives may not have known with absolute certainty from  picking up the signal that the xenomorph was dangerous, but only suspected this, is that correct?

Comment: Was there even that kind of informational content in the signal in the first place?  Navigational buoys don't transmit that there are basaltic rocks at a certain depth, they just warn "keep away from this location."  It seems you're making a huge assumption here.  Why did they investigate?  "We've picked up a signal and _it's not from any known ship or base_!"

Answer (score 2):

In short, we don't know. The signal was presumed by Weyland Yutani scientists to be sufficiently worthwhile investigating to divert a relatively inexpensive space-truck and its eminently expendable crew to go look at it on the downlow, complete with a robot minder to make sure that WYs interests are at the forefront.

It's not even especially clear whether the signal they detected was ultimately determined to be a warning or a distress beacon (or some combination of the both, although it's later described as the latter) and there's no mention of the *translated content* in the films or their supplementary materials.

You can hear the broadcast itself below.